Wrong path for my default image Django app
I'm making a music streaming website with Django, and I want to display the playlists on the homepage. All is working except for the playlists, for which I didn't upload an image. I set a playlist default image, but the browser doesn't find the default image because of the wrong path. How can i fix it? (Probably it's an easy thing, but I'm new to Django...)
html:
{% for playlist in my_playlists %}
<a href="{% url 'music:playlist' playlist.playlist_id %}"><img src="{{ playlist.image.url}}" alt="playlist image"></a>
{% endfor %}

models.py:
class Playlist(models.Model):
playlist_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
playlist_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="name")
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="playlist_images/", validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png'])], default="images/music-placeholder.png")
plays = models.IntegerField(default=0)
songs = models.ManyToManyField(Song, related_name='playlist')
slug = models.SlugField()

class Song(models.Model):
song_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
artist = models.CharField(max_length=50)
album = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
genre = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, default='Album')
song = models.FileField(upload_to="songs/", validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['mp3', 'wav'])], default="name")
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="songimage/", validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png'])], default="https://placehold.co/300x300/png")
data = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
slug = models.SlugField()

views.py:
def homepage(request):
songs = Song.objects.all()
user = request.user
if user.is_authenticated:
    my_playlists = Playlist.objects.filter(user=user)
return render(request, 'homepage.html', {'songs': songs, 'my_playlists': my_playlists})

setting.py:
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

I got this error:
Not Found: /media/media/images/music-placeholder.png but the path should be this /media/images/music-placeholder.png:


Actually Playlist.image.url is located at /media/playlist_images/IMAGE. That error is definitely not related to Playlist. You should look at Song as a probable culprit.

@ChukwujiobiCanon i've added the song model if you can check...

Have you included the media url in your root url conf?
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # your other urls here
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Also make sure you've set the MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT in your settings file too.
Usually something like this:
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

Then I think you should be able to access the uploaded media files from the template with <img src="media/image_path"/>
EDIT:
If you're actually trying to show a static image, make sure the STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT are set in settings and included in your url conf. You can then use the static template tag to render:
{% load static %}
...
<img src="{% static '<path_to_file>.jpg' %}" alt="My image">


the image is in 'media' directory, not in static one. I've already set MEDIA_URL, MEDIA_ROOT, STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT

I think if it's a placeholder and not an uploaded image, it should be a static file

i have a directory in media that contains the not uploaded images
